# Jquery cycle change hide function to disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jquery cycle as a carousel.  I'd like to add some extra functionality to the nav buttons so that the previous button is disabled when at the start of the slideshow and the next button is disabled at the end of the slideshow.

A partial solution can be seen here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html, but I do not want to hide (display:none) the button - I want to give it a class="disabled".

I'm having trouble adapting this script to do so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        next:   '#mycarousel-next', 
        prev:   '#mycarousel-prev',
        after:   onAfter,
        pause: true,
        nowrap: true,
    });
});
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    $('#mycarousel-prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#mycarousel-next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
}
</script>
```

I guess I'm needing to bring $('#mycarousel-next').attr('disabled', ''); into the above statement, but my javascript is poor :(

Many thanks in advance for any help

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight-forward.  If you are at the first or last slide, add the `disabled` class.
Always remove the `disabled` class from both first, or else you will always stay disabled after you reach either end.  This assumes you have css defined for `disabled`.

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide;

    $('#mycarousel-prev, #mycarousel-next').removeClass('disabled');

    if(index == 0) {
        $('#mycarousel-prev').addClass('disabled');
    } else if(index == (opt.slideCount-1)) {
        $('#mycarousel-next').addClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

If you are using buttons which you actually want to disable, you would need to change the code to this:

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide;

    $('#mycarousel-prev, #mycarousel-next').attr('disabled', '');

    if(index == 0) {
        $('#mycarousel-prev').attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else if(index == (opt.slideCount-1)) {
        $('#mycarousel-next').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeff, many thanks for your Answer.  I tried it briefly and can see the disabled class being added perfectly.  But there's an issue of timing when the prev or next buttons are pressed mid transition.  I'm pretty sure this is nothing to do with adding the class though.  I need to dig around a bit - I'm sure I saw mention of this kind of jumping of the slides somewhere.

Update - the jumping/jerking can be seen on this demo http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html if the nav links are pressed during transition.  Hmmm.